# Show warning when a class is imported in python

Tags: python, exception, warnings, deprecation-warning

I have a class in a different module and I want to show a `DeprecationWarning` when that class is imported. What will be the right way to do so?

module 1 contains -

```py
class Test:
    pass
```

module 2 contains -

```py
from module1 import Test #this line should show a DeprecationWarning.
```

Comment: Although common sense dictates it by default, you should probably make the fact that you want to be able to use the class, explicit.

Comment: would this be a good subject matter for meta classes?

on the`__init__` side o things you only get it with a never seen before class.  would this be a good use of*if-you-gotta-ask-aint-needin* metaclassses?

Answer (score 4):

The import will execute the class definition, so put the warning there:

```
class Test:
    raise DeprecationWarning('This class is deprecated')
```

Comment: With my current implementation, the __init__ method of class Test calls a method of a different class. I want to keep that behavior with a warning for now, due to some dependencies.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Of course, you can also raise a warning in `__init__` if you prefer. Then you would get a warning when making an instance of the class, but not on import.

Comment: It should be noted that `import` happens across the entire module indiscriminately, so whether you did `from module1 import Test`, `import module1`, or `from module1 import OtherClass`, it always yields the same result.

Comment: If you import more than once, does it show the message twice?  Against the *importing* module?  It'll be in `sys.modules`.  Good idea tho.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [[Python 3.Docs]: warnings - Warning control](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings), which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> *Changed in version 3.2*: [DeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning) **is now ignored by default** in addition to [PendingDeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PendingDeprecationWarning).

so, you'll have to "manually" enable it, otherwise it won't be visible when importing *mod00*. This way:

- The warning will be displayed when **importing or executing** the module
- The class can be **instantiated** as well

*mod00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("default", category=DeprecationWarning, module=__name__)

print("Module mod00")


class Dummy:
    warnings.warn("Dummy class is deprecated", category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Execute module mod00")
```

*mod01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mod00 import Dummy


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Execute module mod01")
    dummy = Dummy()
    print(dummy)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060486000>sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m mod00
> Module mod00
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060486000\mod00.py:9: DeprecationWarning: Dummy class is deprecated
>   class Dummy:
> Execute module mod00
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" mod00.py
> Module mod00
> mod00.py:9: DeprecationWarning: Dummy class is deprecated
>   class Dummy:
> Execute module mod00
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import mod00"
> Module mod00
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060486000\mod00.py:9: DeprecationWarning: Dummy class is deprecated
>   class Dummy:
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m mod01
> Module mod00
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060486000\mod00.py:9: DeprecationWarning: Dummy class is deprecated
>   class Dummy:
> Execute module mod01
> <mod00.Dummy object at 0x000001EBBC685488>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In your `module1.py`'s `Test` class. add a warning in your init method:

```
import warnings


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        warnings.warn('This class is deprecated', DeprecationWarning)
```

This will give you the below output, where if you hover on `Test`, you'll see a warning.

For that, you'll have to initialize the `Test` class.

[image]

If you want to show a warning on the import statement, you can call the warning in the `module1.py` file itself. However, that will happen for all your Classes in your `module1.py` file if you import them.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Add this `code` to your `index` page:

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

Comment: Is this Python? What is `error_reporting`? What is `ini_set`?